# Error with finding area of ​​the intersection of two rectangles (objective-c)

Tags: objective-c

I make program, which will find area of ​​the intersection of two rectangles. I have height, width and coordinates of this rectangles.

But it wont work! Xcode terminates program with "Thread 1: SIGNAL SIGABRT" on this line (Rectangle.m):

`reswidth = (origin.x + width) - (second.origin.x + second.width);`

So, here's my code:

main.m:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "Rectangle.h"
#import "XYPoint.h"

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [NSAutoreleasePool new];
    Rectangle *myrect1 = [Rectangle new];
    Rectangle *myrect2 = [Rectangle new];
    XYPoint *temp = [XYPoint new];

    [temp setX: 200 andY: 420];
    [myrect1 setOrigin:temp];
   [temp setX: 400 andY: 300];
   [myrect2 setOrigin:temp];
   [temp dealloc];

   [myrect1 setWidth:250 andHeight:75];
   [myrect2 setWidth:100 andHeight:180];

   double print = [myrect1 intersect:myrect2];

   NSLog(@"%g", print);

   [pool drain];

   return 0;
```

}

Rectangle.h:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "XYPoint.h"

@interface Rectangle : NSObject
{
double width;
double height;
XYPoint *origin;
}

@property double width, height;

-(XYPoint *) origin;
-(void) setOrigin: (XYPoint *) pt;
-(void) setWidth: (double) w andHeight: (double) h;
-(double) area;
-(double) perimeter;
-(double) intersect: (Rectangle *) second;

@end
```

Rectangle.m:

```
#import "Rectangle.h"

@implementation Rectangle

@synthesize width, height;

-(void) setOrigin:(XYPoint *)pt
{
    origin = [[XYPoint alloc] init];
    [origin setX: pt.x andY: pt.y];
}

-(void) setWidth: (double) w andHeight: (double) h
{
    width = w;
    height = h;
}

-(double) area
{
    return width * height;
}

-(double) perimeter
{
    return (width + height) * 2;
}

-(double) intersect:(Rectangle *) second
{
    double result,reswidth,resheight;
    reswidth = (origin.x + width) - (second.origin.x + second.width);
    if (reswidth<0) reswidth *= -1;
    resheight = (origin.y + height) - (second.origin.y + second.height);
    if (resheight<0) resheight *= -1;
    result = reswidth * resheight;
    if (result<0) result *= -1;
    return result;
}
@end
```

XYPoint.h:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface XYPoint : NSObject
{
    double x;
    double y;
}

@property double x,y;

-(void) setX:(double) xVal andY: (double) yVal;

@end
```

XYPoint.m:

```
#import "XYPoint.h"

@implementation XYPoint

@synthesize x,y;

-(void) setX:(double) xVal andY: (double) yVal
{
    x=xVal;
    y=yVal;
}

@end
```

Thanks!!!!

Comment: `XYPoint` doesn't need to be an Objective-C object; that's very wasteful.  Demote it to a `struct`.

Comment: Or better still uses the pre-existing `NSPoint`.

Comment: @trojanfoe Ok, I'll use this way in the future. But now I just study this programming language and I don't know anything about struct and NSPoint. But it's temporarily! I'll read about this stuff in the following chapters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not implement the method `-(XYPoint*) origin` in the rectangle class, so you crash when you do `second.origin`. Just make origin into a property in the rectangle class and it should work. Also don't use the new method too much, it's bad practice and stops you from seeing other init methods that might be implemented

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll be more watchful next time! :D